# code behind file for aspx in sharepoint

Tags: 2010, assembly-references, codebehind

I am trying to add code behind file for .aspx file of sharepoint site pages. I followed the instructions given on this link [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb986729(v=office.12).aspx)

But I am getting this error

> Could not load the assembly 'CustomPage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d8b1948ab52231c9'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page

I have installed the .dll file in GAC. I have typed the above assembly details using gacutil.

The page directive looks as follows :

```
    <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> 
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" 
meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPages.Document" 
Language="C#" Inherits="CustomPage.CustomFile, CustomPage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d8b1948ab52231c9" %>
 <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

And I am not able to find any error in my .aspx page too. Is the error because of some safe controls of sharepoint.

**Update:** found the culprit. The code-behind file was initally compiled against the .Net 4.5 framework; once compiled against the 3.5 version (SP 2010 requires that), everything started to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assembly declaration seems wrong. Report here the Page directive, so we can see what's wrong.

Anyway, it should resemble this:

```
Inherits="AssemblyNameSpace.CustomPageClassName, AssemblyNameSpace,Version=1.0.0.0,..."
```

Comment: I have updated my question @MdMazzotti

Comment: @ABeginner try adding this: <%@ Assembly Name="CustomPage.CustomFile, CustomPage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d8b1948ab52231c9" %>

Comment: I got this error on adding the assembly directive : The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Comment: @ABeginner Are you sure you compiled it targeting the .NET 3.5 framework version?

Comment: No, I compiled it in .net framework 4.5 @MdMazzotti

Comment: Ah, ah! That's why it's complaining :) SP 2010 is still on 3.5. You *must* compile your code behind class with the 3.5 version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23076/discussion-between-a-beginner-and-mdmazzotti).